# How to get the central administration URL using jquey in SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Get URL central administrator using jquery in SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

Which page you are trying to run this jQuery code of?

because you can easily get the current site URL in jQuery using the following:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
```

Comment: thanks ,But  I need central admin URL in site collection level because i am getting the central admin group "Farm Administrators" i am getting in site collection please tell me any possible way.